# How to extend the scope of Docker Macvlan driver from Local to Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I am working on a requirement where we need to create network in which **host server should not access the containers**. We have achieved for **single server using Docker Macvlan Network** and when extending the same to the cluster with Docker swarm realized that the **scope of the Macvlan driver is local.**

```
# docker network ls 
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE 
c1e162df6ba0        bridge              bridge             local 
dd4c37820549        docker_gwbridge     bridge             local 
c88f997a2fa7        host                host               local 
3afvn8qnwl1f        ingress             overlay            swarm 
c4899a391b91        isolated_nw1        macvlan            local 
1df2947aad7b        none                null               local 
31tlgcm33m3b        swarm_network       overlay            swarm
```

So my question **is it possible to create a network using macvlan driver which can be extended to swarm**?

If not possible with macvlan **what is the way that we can do this**?

Answer (score 0):

Macvlan driver cannot be extended to Swarm. Only overlay driver can be extended to Swarm at this point(https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_network/). 
Is the reason that you are using macvlan driver to prevent host from talking to container or for container to reach underlay network directly?
If you just want container to not talk to host, you can use overlay network. containers in overlay network have 2 interfaces, 1 in overlay and another docker_gwbridge. address in overlay network is not reachable from host. address in docker_gwbridge would still be reachable from host.

Answer (score 0):

If interested, there is the ability to use locally scoped Docker drivers in Swarm mode coming in the next release. This would let you use Macvlan with swarm etc. Example usage with 17.06 can be found here: https://github.com/mark-church/docs/blob/master/local-scope-swarm-networking.md There are instructions to get the binary installed and examples for the various drivers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Support for **macvlan** in docker swarm was added in version [17.06.0-ce](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#17060-ce) *(28th of June 2017)*.

> **NETWORKING**
>
> - Add Support swarm-mode services with node-local networks such as macvlan, ipvlan, bridge, host.

More information can be found in [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32981) merged pull request

**Example:**

```
node1# docker network create --config-only --subnet 192.168.10.0/24 --gateway 192.168.10.1 --opt parent=enp8s0 --opt macvlan_mode=bridge mv-config

node2# docker network create --config-only --subnet 192.168.20.0/24 --gateway 192.168.20.1 --opt parent=eth1 --opt macvlan_mode=bridge mv-config

docker network create -d macvlan --scope=swarm --config-from mv-config swarm-mv-nw
```